# Android App crashes due to java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, gradle, soundcloud

I execute my Android App, correctly compiled, and when I try to access to some SoundCloud APIs it crashes. Here's what is reported in the `Logcat`

**Logcat**

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de.voidplus.soundcloud.SoundCloud
            at it.polimi.dima.sound4u.activity.FirstAccessActivity$LoginTask.onPreExecute(FirstAccessActivity.java:75)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
            at it.polimi.dima.sound4u.activity.FirstAccessActivity.doLogin(FirstAccessActivity.java:56)
            at it.polimi.dima.sound4u.fragment.FirstAccessFragment$1.onClick(FirstAccessFragment.java:76)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here my `gradle.build` file.

**gradle.build**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.1+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.17.0-rc'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.17.0-rc'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.17.0-rc'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.17.0-rc'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.17.0-rc'
    compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:1.17.0-rc'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:14.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.3'
    compile 'com.eclipsesource.minimal-json:minimal-json:0.9.1'
    compile files('libs/sound4uendpoints-v1-1.17.0-rc-SNAPSHOT.jar')
    compile files('libs/soundscoud-unoff.jar')
}
```

As you see I have a lot of external dependencies and the `soundscoud-unoff.jar` is responsible for the crash. It seems that this library is not in the buildpath of the application. I use IntelliJ Idea, can someone please fix this?

Comment: Can you post a link to the soundcloud jars? I suspect the paths don't line up

Comment: The link is [here](https://github.com/voidplus/soundcloud-java-library) on GitHub. I unzip the download below and copied the JAR in the libs folder. I also have the same problem with the official ones here adding the `compile 'com.soundcloud:java-api-wrapper:1.3.1'` as reported in Maven Central.